# Create NSString with 'N' Unicode Characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to create a string containing (unicode) 'stars' based on an integer rating. I currently have:

```
NSMutableString *stars = [NSMutabelString stars];
for (int i = 0; i < rating; i++)
{
    [stars appendString:@"\u2605"];
}
```

However, I find this a bit ugly. Does a way exist to construct such a string without using this looping method? Something using the string formats?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure - to do this on a single line you can use the `stringByPaddingToLength` method:

```
[@"" stringByPaddingToLength: rating withString: @"\u2605" startingAtIndex:0];
```

...should hopefully do the trick for you - and no need to create any subclasses or categories, etc!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a category for NSString with an extra method - say, +(NSString)stringForRating:(NSInteger)rating, and move the loop in there. Then whenever you need a star string, just call that.